# How to extract slug from URL with regular expression in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I'm struggling with Python's `re`. I don't know how to solve the following problem in a clean way.

I want to extract a part of an URL,

What I tried so far:

```
url = http://www.example.com/this-2-me-4/123456-subj
m = re.search('/[0-9]+-', url)
m = m.group(0).rstrip('-')
m = m.lstrip('/')
```

This leaves me with the desired output `123456`, but I feel this is not the proper way to extract the slug.

How can I solve this quicker and cleaner?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a capturing group by putting parentheses around the part of the regex that you want to capture `(...)`. You can get the contents of a capturing group by passing in its number as an argument to `m.group()`:

```
>>> m = re.search('/([0-9]+)-', url)
>>> m.group(1) 
123456
```

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax):

> `(...)`
>   Matches whatever regular expression is inside the parentheses, and indicates the start and end of a group; the contents of a group can be retrieved after a match has been performed, and can be matched later in the string with the `\number` special sequence, described below. To match the literals `'('` or `')'`, use `\(` or `\)`, or enclose them inside a character class: `[(] [)]`.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to use `urllib.parse` combined with a capturing group for mildly cleaner code.

```
import urllib.parse, re

url = 'http://www.example.com/this-2-me-4/123456-subj'
parsed = urllib.parse.urlparse(url)
path = parsed.path
slug = re.search(r'/([\d]+)-', path).group(1)
print(slug)
```

Result:

```
123456
```

In Python 2, use `urlparse` instead of `urllib.parse`.

Comment: Could you please explain to me why you find using urllib.parse to be cleaner? Because the rest of your answer is the same as @Nefta's…

Comment: @MartinBetz Well, you're parsing a URL, aren't you? I don't know what the rest of your code looks like, so it's entirely possible that this might be overkill for you, but just for the sake of argument, what if you have a url like `http://foo.com/bar/123456-subj?arg=/789-`? That's not a valid URL, sure (the query should be %-encoded), but I can imagine some situations in which one might have to deal with that.

Comment: Thanks for explaining! The answer is a bit outside the scope of the question, so I chose the other one as best fit, but I learnt something extra from your answer!

Answer (score 0):

if you wants to find all the slugs available in a URL you can use this code.

```
from slugify import slugify

url = "https://www.allrecipes.com/recipe/79300/real-poutine?search=random/some-name/".split("/")

for i in url:
    i = i.split("?")[0] if "?" in i else i
    if "-" in i  and slugify(i) == i:
        print(i)
```

This will provide with an output of

```
real-poutine
some-name
```